# Allow slashes in url parameters (useParams) react router v6

Tags: react-router

I have a route like this:

```
<Route path="signup/:id" element={<SignUpPage/>}/>
```

But the problem is that the id in the url is a client id and it contains many trailing slashes (eg. signup/jhagsd==/sfdfsdf/dsdfgf) and due to this the router considers this as a new route instead of a param after "signup/".
How to extract everything after "signup/" as param from useParams() hook?

Comment: You can't. AFAIK the route param `id` will have the value `"jhagsd=="`. You will need to serialize everything after `"/signup"` into something that isn't still a valid set of URL path segments. Or use the queryString params.